# If I run a script through ssh to GCP, will it be interrupted if my local machine goes to sleep?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a script that should take about 8 hours or so to run on a GCP VM instance with 8CPUs. I am somewhat new to cloud computing and am a bit nervous to set up ssh, run my python file and walk away.

If I ssh into a GCP VM instance, start a python script and walk away, will it continue to run even if my computer goes to sleep? My intuition is no, as this seems to be the whole point of cloud computing, but I want to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, if your computer goes to sleep and your ssh session closes, your script will stop.

To prevent this, you can use `&` and then `disown`  to push your script to the background and remove the process from the shell's job control, but it still leaves it connected to the terminal.

For example:

1. I ran my script

`./script.sh  &`

2. We will obtain the JobID, because it will start running in background:

`[1] 7812`

3. With this JobID I can run the `disown` command to remove the process from the shell's job control:

`disown 7812`

At this point, you can close your ssh session and the script will continue working.

Alternatively, you also can use `Screen`. When screen is called, it creates a single window with a shell in it (or the specified command) and then gets out of your way so that you can use the program as you normally would.

Screen will keep running even if your session gets disconnected. When you reconnect to the server you can reconnect to the screen session and everything will be as if nothing happened, this is a good option if you want to see the results of your script in the standard output.

You can consult the official documentation on the following [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).
Also, you can use the following [guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) to know how to use screen.

Additionally, you can see the following [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698), where the community explains the difference between `nohup`, `disown` and `&` .

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: I started using `screen` today. It does exactly what I need.

Comment: I think Screen is a very good option, I have found another guide.
You can check it in case you need more examples for Screen.

[Stayin' alive with Screen](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-gnu_screen/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you close your SSH session your script stops. I usually use `nohup` command for this

```
nohup <command + param> &
```

*I assume that you are under linux*

Comment: Well, I'm on windows but when I ssh into my instance it gives me a terminal that is linux based (I think). I'll research `nohup` and give it a try and report back. Thank you.

Comment: would `nohup` work for the IOS Google Cloud Console as well? i.e., if I run a command with `nohup`, and then close the app, would it still run?

Comment: nohup is a linux command, not IOS dependent.